# How can I load a remote file using jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm currently using this code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="div"></div>
<script>
var timer = 10;
var source = 'file.php';

$(document).ready(function() {
  refresh();
  setInterval(function() { refresh() }, timer * 1000);
});

function refresh() {
    $('.div').load(source);
}
</script>
```

But, if I put a link to the file.php file, say http://example.com/file.php, it doesn't load anything.

What I would like to do is to be able to load remote files.

How can I go about doing this?
Or is this disabled for security reasons?

My console shoots the following error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load SOURCE. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'URL' is therefore not allowed access.`

SOURCE is the place I was trying to load from, and URL is the place I was trying to load the source.

Comment: You need to run the code on a web server, not from your local hard drive. What JavaScript errors do you see in your browser console?

Comment: I was running it on a web server. I didn't check for any errors.

Comment: Checking for errors is the first thing you should have done; post them here verbatim if you don't understand them.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a Javascript developer. I'll learn.

I'll check for errors now, thank you.

Comment: Error added to the main question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright.

My issue was that I didn't have CORS enabled.

I fixed this by adding the following code to the top of my request file (file.php)

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
```

Now it works.

Allowing the origin to be anyone is insecure and I don't recommend but for what I'm doing, it's fine.

Comment: Keep in mind that [`'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin) will allow ANY other site to load this file via AJAX as well, whether you want them to or not. You're better off replacing `*` with the narrowest domain possible.

Comment: Can I allow multiple domains with commas? Like `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: tumblr.com, facebook.com');`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains

Answer (score 1):

I think the jquery load() function can only load content from the same domain.

You might be able to fetch the results with a crossdomain ajax call (documentation on http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), depending on what you are trying to fetch.

Comment: All the script really does is print a string of text and some HTML. Should I be able to do it?

Comment: Error added to the main question.

Answer (score 0):

from what i understand you are trying to get the 'file.php' Code text .. this is not possible Server side scripts only output their Screen . e.g echos / print / Var dump.

if you are trying to activate a php script at a remote server you can use post / get using JQuery and get the script reply.

Comment: Error added to the main question.